# Problems with bash and its quoting rules

Tags: linux, bash, shell, quotes

I'm having a problem with bash's quoting rules and I don't know how to solve it.
I want to have a variable inside some kind of config file, where a list of commandline options can be specified. In my case it's for rsync:
rsync has the commandline-option '--rsh', which allows you to specify the remoteshell it's using on the other side. For example:

```
rsync -v --rsh="ssh -p4711 -lhttp" /tmp/testfile remoteMachine.x:/tmp/testfile
```

This works perfectly! But if you try to do this inside a script, where you want to allow all options to be specified in a variable, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

OPTS="-v --rsh=\"ssh -p4711 -lhttp\""
rsync $OPTS testfile remoteMachine.x:/tmp/testfile
```

When exexuting this scrip, it will fail with this error:

```
rsync: -p4711: unknown option
```

This is, because bash is doing some nasty quoting/escaping and I can't figure out why (You can see what bash's doing with 'bash -x'):

```
+ OPTS='-v --rsh="ssh -p4711 -lhttp"'
+ rsync -v '--rsh="ssh' -p4711 '-lhttp"' testfile remoteMachine.x:/tmp/testfile
```

I tried multiple combinations of weak and strong quotes(", ') but nothing works... Can you help me, why bash is doing that and how I can solve this strange behavior?

Thanks and greetings from Cologne!

Comment: `it's quoting rules` -- yet another problem with quoting rules :P

Comment: Nirk, "its" is correct.

Comment: Some light reading to support @user000001's answer: [BashFAQ/050 - I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array:

```
OPTS=(-v --rsh="ssh -p4711 -lhttp")
rsync "${OPTS[@]}" testfile remoteMachine.x:/tmp/testfile
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped :) Bit weird, that i can't write it inside a string and prevent bash from doing this nasty quoting, but it works :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two alternatives: pass the `--rsh` options through `RSYNC_RSH` environment variable or pass the port and login options to `rsync` directly with `--port` and the `login@host:path` syntax